# how to manipulate laravel filament Sum::make() values from Summaries table builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

So laravel filament have a Sum::make() in summaries table builder
[Filament Summaries](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/summaries#sum)

```
use Filament\Tables\Columns\Summarizers\Sum;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn;
 
TextColumn::make('price')
    ->summarize(Sum::make()) // sum the price column
```

What I want to do is to divide the above sum by 1000, but I don't know how? is it possible, I have read the docs but could not find any clue about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do a custom sumarizer.

"You may create a custom summary by returning the value from the using() method:"

```
TextColumn::make('price')
  ->summarize(Summarizer::make()
    ->label('Sum / 1000')
    ->using(fn (Builder $query): int => $query->sum('price') / 1000 ))
```